# How do you merge multiple (5 columns) series data in Pandas to then use mode?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a very interesting problem that I have tried to research and can't get exactly what i'm looking for. So, let's say I have multiple columns (series) of data that I want to merge together so that I can then use the .mode function on to get the most-used occurrence across all. In my case, there are 5 series with work hour numbers and all have identical length of values AND the same index starting point.

```
fistNumSeries = (SerSep.N0)
print (fistNumSeries)
secdNumSeries = (SerSep.N1)
print (secdNumSeries)
```

etc....

which yields me to:

```
0       01
1       02
2       10
3       12
[4 rows x 2 columns]

0       07
1       03
2       16
3       02
[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

....etc..

Perfect. However, the output I'd like is to have all columns (in my case 5 of them) merged into just one column (duplicates allowed, indexes don't matter) so that I can conduct a .mode() to see what the top values are without caring about the index. So, for the example above I'm looking for an output such as:

```
0       01
1       02
2       10
3       12
4       07
5       03
6       16
7       02
```

[8 rows x 2 columns]

I've looked into the append, concat, even the add etc. but I can't seem to get the output into one the way its looking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly did you try with `.concat`? Did you use `ignore_index=True`? e.g. `pd.concat([N0, N1], ignore_index=True).mode()`

Answer (score 0):

use the pd.concat() function to concatenate the columns together along the axis of columns (axis=1), and then use the reset_index() method to reset the index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

SerSep = {
    'N0': pd.Series([1, 2, 10, 12]),
    'N1': pd.Series([7, 3, 16, 2]),
    'N2': pd.Series([4, 5, 2, 9]),
    'N3': pd.Series([6, 1, 11, 3]),
    'N4': pd.Series([2, 4, 10, 1])
}

merged_series = pd.concat(SerSep.values())

most_common_values = merged_series.mode()

print(most_common_values)
```

Output:

```
0    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example to demonstrate how to use the `.mode()` function:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.Series(range(5))
>>> y = pd.Series(range(3))
>>> z = pd.Series(range(2,5))
>>> pd.concat([x,y,z], ignore_index=True).mode()
0    2
dtype: int64
>>>
```